# 'str' object has no attribute 'verified'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am including OTP in my project with twilio. But When verifying phone number it throws following error.

```
phone.verified = True
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'verified'
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'

    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def send_sms_code(request, format=None):
    time_otp = pyotp.TOTP(request.user.key, interval=10000)
    time_otp = time_otp.now()
    user_phone_number = request.user.phone
    client.messages.create(
                    body="Your verification code is "+time_otp,
                    from_=twilio_phone,
                    to=user_phone_number
                )
    return Response(status=200)


@api_view(['GET'])
def verify_phone(request, sms_code, format=None):
    code = int(sms_code)
    if request.user.authenticate(code):
        phone = request.user.phone
        phone.verified = True
        phone.save()
        return Response(dict(detail = "Phone number verified successfully"),status=201)
    return Response(dict(detail='The provided code did not match or has expired'),status=200)
```

it sends me a verification code but When I am going to verify it does not work properly. I know where the problem is but How can I solve it? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Is verified on the user model or a separate Phone model? If it is the latter, `phone` on the `User` model should be a `ForeignKeyField` to the Phone model rather than a `CharField` and your code should work. If verified is on the `User` model, see the provided answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your api view sets phone = `request.user.phone` which is a string. You then use phone as if it is a `User` object by accessing the verified property on it. Instead, your view should be:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def verify_phone(request, sms_code, format=None):
  ...
  if request.user.authenticate(code):
    user = request.user # set user as a User object.
    user.verified = True
    user.save()
    return Response(...)
  return Response(...)
```

It looks like you don't even use the phone variable so you don't really need it with the information you gave us.